# AutoComplete Algorithm

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using [google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#call_gmsplacesclient) to implement autocomplete suggestion in iOS application. As  it is a paid request so the api calls should be optimized. Is there any standard algorithm or a way to achieve it?
I know api calls can not be 100% perfect but I would like to optimize it to the best.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901831/algorithm-for-autocomplete) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783652/what-is-the-best-autocomplete-suggest-algorithm-datastructure-c-c), but it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can save some data in your local database by following user's search-word what he/she frequently searches.

If again searches same area then local database can supply its data. If there is a new data in search box then google places API will provide data.

By the way it is google's business to sell data. and I don't know how much capable we are to optimize our API calls.

Comment: How can we know which words does the user search frequently ? I know we can not make the api calls 100% perfect but I just want to optimize the api calls.