# architecture: building text suggestions based on existing text

Tags: text-classification

trying build a text suggestions similar to stackoverflow  question suggestions. Do not know where to start from. Any suggestions what tools/servers/algorithms i should be researching. Does this come under text classification?

Any links towards this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **[string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)**. They try to find a place where one or several strings (also called patterns) are found within a larger string or text.

The following links help you understand this topic:

[Algorithm for autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901831/algorithm-for-autocomplete)

[What is the best autocomplete/suggest algorithm,datastructure [C++/C]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783652/what-is-the-best-autocomplete-suggest-algorithm-datastructure-c-c)

https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/10-string-algorithms.pdf